# virsh qemu kvm editing xml has no effect

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

When I try to add a network section to a kvm/qemu xml, the xml wont update with the information.

When I edit the uuid, or make a mistake, i get an error. if i change the memory amount, it reverts to the original also.

I try editing with dump-xml vm vm.xml and define vm.xml, and also with edit vm.xml, neither works.

I've mostly been editing with the vm shut off

How do I edit my xml so changes take effect?

Sorry for my error. When I update the memory amount while also adding a network section, the memory amount changes while the network section isn't added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the man page:

**define** *file*

```
a domain from an XML <file>. The domain definition is registered but
not started. If domain is already running, the changes will take
effect on the next boot.
```

**edit** *domain*

```
Edit the XML configuration file for a domain, which will affect the
next boot of the guest. This is equivalent to: 

virsh dumpxml --inactive --security-info domain > domain.xml vi
domain.xml (or make changes with your other text editor) virsh define
domain.xml except that it does some error checking.
```

It's not possible to edit the XML without restarting.

For editing networks, net-update might work: `virsh net-update default add ip-dhcp-host "<host mac='32:34:30:30:30:30' name='vm1' ip='192.168.122.30' />" --live --config`
But depending on your libvirt version, even that doesn't make libvirt give the server a new ip instantly (this has something to do with dnsmasq not reloading / restarting).

Comment: Thankyou.  When i use the edit command, changing the memory amount and adding a <network> section, the xml updates the memory amount but doesn't add the <network> section.

Comment: there's no <network> section in a domains xml file. the <network> is defined  in the networks xml. list networks with `virsh net-list` and dump the networks xml with `virsh net-dumpxml <network_name>`. see https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsNICSVirtual and https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html

Comment: And libvirt removes the section automatically. Thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you been editing the xml directly? You're really supposed to run `virsh edit VMNAME`

Comment: Yes, I've been trying both the virsh edit command, and the virsh define command.